# how to get the first occurring of an element from every row in a 2D numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2d numpy array. I am looking for the indices of the first occurance of a specific element in each row. The output will be an (n x 2) array, where n is the number of rows and every entry contains the x and y coordinate of the first occurance of that specific element.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by the "s and y coordinate" so I'm assuming you mean the row and column position.

```
import numpy as np
np.array([(s, list(row).index(your_element)) for s,row in enumerate(your_array)])
```

Note it will raise `ValueError` if `your_element` wasn't contained in some row.

The following version will give you an output which may contain fewer rows than the input, but won't raise `ValueError` for the case where `your_element` was missing from a row.

```
np.array([(s, list(row).index(your_element)) for s,row in enumerate(your_array) if your_element in row])
```

Comment: yes you understood it correctly... i wanted to write x and y coordinate... Well, could there be any solution which contains only the the rows with the indices of first element where the element exits without -1? Or we can do any post processing to avoid it?
thanks

Comment: what behaviour do you want the code to you have for the case where your_element was not contained in a row?  you could  a) first remove those rows from the input   b) fill the y position of output with a placeholder value  c) raise an exception

Comment: well the rows in the input should not be removed because it will later be used for indexing. Also removing rows will disturb the indexing. The output should be like `[(row_num,col_num),(row_num,col_num),(row_num,col_num),...,(row_num,col_num)]` where the first element in the result tell the row and column of the first occrance of the specific element in that row and so on... I hope that now it will be clear... Please let me know if there is any problem. Thanks

Comment: it will not disturb the indexing if you are indexing into the cleaned up array.  if you want to index into the original array then you either need to  a) handle the case where is no valid col_num for a particular row, or b) allow output array to have less rows than input array.  so i must ask again: what behaviour do you want to you have for the case where your_element was not contained in a row?

Comment: @wim... I would go for the second behavior where the number of rows in output are less than the input if the specified element is not contained in the array. Thnaks

Comment: ok, that behaviour can be achieved by adding `if your_element in row` to the list comprehension.  i have edited my answer with that solution.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, you want something like this:

```
import numpy as N
#
nrows=5
ncols=10 
#
a=N.random.random((nrows,ncols))
b=-99*N.ones((nrows,2))
#
for j in range(nrows):
    for i in range(ncols):
        if(a[j,i]<0.5):
            b[j,0]=i
            b[j,1]=j
            continue
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> # generate some fake data:
>>> A = NP.random.randint(5, 10, 100).reshape(10, 10)
>>> A
  array([[5, 7, 8, 8, 5, 6, 6, 9, 6, 9],
        [9, 8, 8, 9, 5, 6, 6, 9, 8, 9],
        [8, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 8, 6, 7],
        [5, 8, 8, 6, 9, 6, 8, 5, 8, 9],
        [6, 9, 8, 8, 5, 7, 6, 5, 7, 6],
        [7, 8, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 8, 6, 8],
        [8, 6, 8, 9, 8, 8, 9, 6, 8, 7],
        [8, 7, 8, 5, 9, 5, 7, 8, 6, 9],
        [9, 6, 5, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 8, 8],
        [6, 8, 5, 8, 6, 5, 8, 6, 8, 5]])

>>> # sort this 2D array along one axis (i chose row-wise)
>>> A = NP.sort(A, axis=1)
>>> A
  array([[5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9],
         [5, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9],
         [5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9],
         [5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9],
         [5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9],
         [6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8],
         [6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9],
         [5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9],
         [5, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9],
         [5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8]])

>>> # now diff the sorted array along the same axis
>>> A1 = NP.diff(A ,axis=1)

>>> # A1 contains non-zero values for "first occurrences" and
>>> # zero values for repeat values
>>> A1
  array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
         [1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
         [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
         [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
         [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
         [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0]])
```

you can reformulate the result, A1, as necessary, e.g., as a *boolean array* having the same shape as A1 in wich each cell is either T/F depending on whether the value in the original matrix represents the first occurrence of that value:

```
>>> ndx = A1==0
>>> ndx
  array([[ True, False,  True,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True],
         [False,  True, False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True],
         [ True, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True,  True, False],
         [ True, False,  True, False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True],
         [ True, False,  True,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False],
         [ True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True],
         [ True, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True],
         [ True, False, False,  True, False,  True,  True, False,  True],
         [False, False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True],
         [ True,  True, False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```